# How to handle/cast an element in C# that was retrieved from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webview2

I have a javascript in my WindowsForms project that fetches the element at the mouse_click posistion.

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    let jsonObject =
    {
        Event: 'click',
        Elements: elem
    };
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(jsonObject);
});
```

This javascript is initialised from:

```
private void WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string script = File.ReadAllText("ElementAtMouse.js");
        WebView2.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name} : {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} : {e1.Message}");
    }
}
```

The element returned from the javascript I am extracting with:

```
private void WebView2_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(e.WebMessageAsJson);
        HtmlElement Elements = (HtmlElement)jsonObject.Elements;
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name} : {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} : {e1.Message}");
    }
}
```

My JsonObject is defined as:

```
public struct JsonObject
{
    public string Event;
    public HtmlElement Elements;          
}
```

The issue I am running into is that I am getting the following error:

```
"Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Elements.jQuery360009814206096004632', line 1, position 59."}"
```

How should I handle/cast the element returned by the JavaScript?

Comment: Do you need to return the *entire* HTMLElement, or can you not just pull properties from it and return a simple datatype, array, or object containing multiple properties which can easily map to a class in your C#

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Ideally I would like to get the entire element that was "clicked".

Comment: What about using nullable? Like:
public HtmlElement? Elements;

Comment: You cannot get a `HtmlElement` from there. This is a .Net generated class, also related to Internet Explorer. What you get from that script is the JSON representation of the partial definition of a HTML element (some static attributes). You have to retrieve other property values while the DOM can be queried (in your script)

Comment: Also, you don't need `elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);`. The clicked element is `e.target`.

Comment: ... To get its properties forgot to mention. Like `e.target.id`, `e.target.tagName` ..etc. Not to pass it itself.

Comment: If you are looking for a DOM API then there are a few 3rd party libraries including https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#dom-access